# Is there a way to detect the "LongClick" event of a NumberPicker in Android?

Tags: android, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I am trying to set the background of the NumberPicker as long as the user either scrolls with a touch swipe gesture or with the long press gesture.
Currently I can only react on a touch swipe gesture.

The following code snippet works, but only if the user performs a touch swipe gesture (like touching the screen and swiping up or down).

```
NumberPicker.OnScrollListener myListener = (view, scrollState) -> {
    if(scrollState == NumberPicker.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        //change background to eg. white
    }
    else {
        //change background  to eg. black
    }
}


myPicker.setOnScrollListener(myListener);
```

However If I long press e.g. on the "3" or "20" as seen in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0J3G.png) the scroll state doesn't change even though the numberPicker is visually scrolling.
**How can I react on such an event?**

I tried to set a setOnLongClickListener (see following code snippet) but I don't even get a LongClick event.

```
View.OnLongClickListener myClickListener = v -> {
    //change background
    return true;
};


myPicker.setOnLongClickListener(myClickListener);
```

Comment: Could you use _NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener_ instead regardless of the gesture that changes the value, or does it have to be a long-click event?

Comment: I think i should add that I only want to change the background to a specific colour as long as there is a user input.
The problem with _NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener_ is that I don't know when to change the background colour back.